# input style with class is overridden by jquery.ui.theme.css

Tags: css, jquery-ui

using jquery-1.6.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.13.min.js.

I have a textbox sitting inside a jquery dialog

```
<div class="chat-response">
    <input class="chat-response-textbox" name="chat-response-textbox" placeholder="Type message here">
</div>
```

I have some associated css which I have made the font size intentionally large:

```
.chat-response-textbox
{
font-size: 20px;
font-family: Arial;
}
```

However when running in Chrome/IE the font size doesn't come out as 20.

In Chrome I can see the style is being taken from  jquery.ui.theme.css

### Elements Window

[image]

### Styles Window

[image]

Why is this occurring given I explicitly assign a class to the input element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all about the [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity). The most-specific selector wins; in this case that's `.ui-widget input`.

Just make your selector more specific than that one, and it'll work:

```
.ui-widget input.chat-response-textbox
{
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to

```
input.chat-response-textbox
```

That makes your style more specific, which should override JQuery UI.

Comment: fyg needs .ui-widget as above

Comment: @wal - I didn't. What browser did you find you needed it on? webkit seems to handle it fine without.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare probably Chrome